# Edit block inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, iframe

I have a wordpress site. I have added a iframe to pull a page from a different website. The iframe is adding a lot of contents which i dont require. How do i hide them from showing inside the iframe ? I tried targeting the div's inside the iframe using css. But nothing seems to happen. Are there any scripts to take control of the elements inside the iframe ?? Please help.

```
<iframe id="foo" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" src="https://www.airboxexpress.com.pa/afiliacion/registro.aspx" width="300" height="150"></iframe>
```

Comment: You can't edit the stylesheet of a cross domain iframe. Security reasons.

Comment: @magnetwd But some scripts will be der right...to find the div inside the iframe nd den hide it...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a two part answer - unless the iframe is **also on your domain** this cannot be done for security reasons. Imagine a iframe to your bank but the form had been changed to post to a malicious server.

If the frame IS on your domain that I would just recommend editing the file as normal in your editor.